# How to remove row, if columns have similar pair of values on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

i have a dataframe:

```
val1      val2
"a"       "b"
"b"       "a"
"c"        "m"
"c"        "m"
"m"        "c"
```

if two columns contain two similar values on same row, that row must be removed. so desired result is:

```
val1      val2
"a"       "b"
"c"        "m"
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What exactly means "similar" here?

Comment: @MichaelButscher there are two same values on rows. so if we have "a"  and  "b" on columns val1 and val2 on row 1 and "b"  and  "a" on columns val1 and val2 on row 2, those rows are duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)/[`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.Series.duplicated) :

```
# is the pair val1/var2 duplicated ?
m = df.agg(lambda x: sorted(list(x)), axis=1).duplicated(keep="first")
​
out = df.loc[~m]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  val1 val2
0  "a"  "b"
2  "c"  "m"
```